# How do I replace all characters in a Python string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found a solution on stackoverflow but it doesn't seem to work. I have made a string scanner that checks for character frequency and then replaces all characters with the "real" characters. I've made sure that the character recognition works but when I try replacing all characters in a string they no longer match up with the expected/calculated characters (when I try replacing for example only 2 characters it works fine and matches up perfectly). Here is my replacement code:

```
print(text.replace(re,'e').replace(rt,'t').replace(ra,'a').replace(ro,'o').replace(ri,'i').replace(rn,'n').replace(rs,'s').replace(rr,'r').replace(rh,'h').replace(rl,'l').replace(ru,'u').replace(rc,'c').replace(rm,'m').replace(rf,'f').replace(ry,'y').replace(rw,'w').replace(rg,'g').replace(rp,'p').replace(rb,'b').replace(rv,'v').replace(rk,'k').replace(rx,'x').replace(rq,'q').replace(rj,'j').replace(rz,'z').replace(rd,'d'))
```

Comment: Has nothing to do with the Cryptography tag.

Comment: Look at `str.translate` and `str.maketrans`

Comment: Each call to replace is operating on the result of the previous. By the time you get to the 14th call, you are guaranteed to be replacing letters that you’ve already replaced. Use .translate as mentioned in the solution below.

Comment: Are `re`/`rt`/`ra` etc. single characters, or multicharacter strings? `str.translate` can only replace based on matches of a single character (the replacement string can be any length).

Comment: On a side note... if `re`/`rt`/`ra` etc... are the *real* characters... it looks like your arguments to replace are the wrong way around anyway...

Comment: @Jon Clements♦ re is equal to the most frequent character. The most frequent character (in longer texts most likely 'e' in the original message) will be replaced with 'e'.

Comment: @ShadowRanger re,rt,... are single characters. I convert a dict to a sorted list of tuples and then set the one with the highest value to be the (single) 'e' string. Like I mentioned in my description it works fine with one or two letters.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [translate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm). Your code would probably look something like

```
text = text.translate(str.maketrans('abcd...', ''.join([ra, rb, rc, rd...]))
```

---